# Visual Studio Unit Test show cout messages from Function under test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

I have a setup very similar to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh598953.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with a Static Library project containing my functionality, as well a test project that obviously references and calls this code.

I have the following test macro/function (basic example) (inside test project)

```
TEST_METHOD(Foo_Test)
{
    Foo.HelloWorld();
}
```

which calls the following function (inside static lib):

```
void Foo::HelloWorld()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

When I run this code through the test explorer tab my test passes fine (obviously in this simple example as there are no asserts) but I don't seem to have any way of analysing the output as it does not go out to console.

It's important to me that my Foo class stays completely portable and does not include any Microsoft or Test specific code, I believe I should be able to test my code through its interface.

My question, why can't I see this output and is there a way I can enable to console output for the messages generated from my unit under test.

Comment: Just stumbling over this older question, trying to the same thing. Did you ever get this resolved ?

Comment: @nick Not that I remember pal! Sorry.

Comment: no worries, thanks for the quick reply ! What i can gather, this is still not possible in 2022. Ridiculous.